# Where to put REST API in Django

Tags: python, django, api, rest

Here is a quote from [Two Scoops of Django: Best Practices For Django 1.6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/098146730X):

> In the past, we placed all API view code into a dedicated Django app
>   called api or apiv1, with custom logic in some of the REST views,
>   serializers, and more. In theory it’s a pretty good approach, but in
>   practice it means we have logic for a particular app in more than just
>   one location.
>
> Our current approach is to lean on URL configuration. When building a
>   project-wide API we write the REST views in the `views.py` modules, wire
>   them into a URLConf called something like `core/api.py` or
>   `core/apiv1.py` and include that from the project root's `urls.py`
>   module. This means that we might have something like the following
>   code:

```
# core/api.py

""" Called from the project root's urls.py URLConf thus:
url(r" ˆ api/", include("core.api"), namespace="api"),
"""

from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url

from flavors import views as flavor_views
from users import views as user_views

urlpatterns = patterns("",
    # {% url "api:flavors" %}
    url(
        regex=r" ˆ flavors/ $ ",
        view=flavor_views.FlavorCreateReadView.as_view(),
        name="flavors"
        ),

    # {% url "api:flavors" flavor.slug %}
    url(
        regex=r" ˆ flavors/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/ $ ",
        view=flavor_views.FlavorReadUpdateDeleteView.as_view(),
        name="flavors"
        ),

    # {% url "api:users" %}
    url(
        regex=r" ˆ users/ $ ",
        view=user_views.UserCreateReadView.as_view(),
        name="users"
        ),

    # {% url "api:users" user.slug %}
    url(
        regex=r" ˆ users/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/ $ ",
        view=user_views.UserReadUpdateDeleteView.as_view(),
        name="users"
        ),
)
```

But I don't understand where to put `core/api.py`. Is this a separate Django app called `core`? Where `api.py` should sit?

Comment: it means create the file above as `core/api.py` (along with an empty `core/__init__.py`) and then add the line `url(r" ˆ api/", include("core.api"), namespace="api")` to the root `urls.py` file

Comment: you don't have to call it `core/api.py` that is just a suggestion from the authors

Comment: @Anentropic, thanks much. Just add it as an answer so I can accept it. Also, what does `we write the REST views in the views.py modules` mean? Can I have a example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means create the file you have as `core/api.py` (along with an empty `core/__init__.py` file) and then add the line `url(r" ˆ api/", include("core.api"), namespace="api")` to the root `urls.py` file of your project.

You don't have to call it `core/api.py`, that is just a suggestion from the authors

> what does we write the REST views in the views.py modules mean?

It means what you've done, for each of the Django apps in your project, such as `flavors`, `users` they will have a `views.py` (or `views/*.py`) in them where you'd put the code for both the API and non-API views. (this is just a sane naming convention, nothing more... Django relies on the `urlpatterns` to tell it how to connect url routes to view code)

It's great to build up stuff like this from scratch as a way to learn Django.  If you're doing a serious REST API project have a look at [Django REST framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/).